Mayer-Vietoris for Morse homology
Let $M$ be a compact oriented manifold with boundary and $(f,X)$ be a Morse-Smale pair on it. We assume that none of the critical points lie on the boundary, which can then be decomposed as $\partial M = \partial_+ M\sqcup\partial_- M$ where in the first component the vector field $X$ points outwards and in the second inwards. The Morse homology $MH(M, \partial_+ M, \mathbb Z)$ is defined as the homology of the complex $(C_*(f), \partial_X)$ where $C_*$ is the union of the $C_k$ the set of critical points of index $k$ and the differential $\partial_X |_{C_k}:C_k\to C_{k-1}$ is defined by $\partial_X (p)=\sum_{q\in C_{k-1}} n(p,q) q$ where $n(p,q)$ is the signed number of trajectories from $p$ to $q$ along $X$.
Suppose $M=A\cup B$ is an open cover such that $A\cap B$ is connected. Assuming that the boundary of $A$ and $B$ doesn't contain any of the critical points, in each of the sets $A,B, A\cap B$ the restriction of $(f,X)$ is a Morse-Smale pair and hence defines a Morse homology. Is there a Mayer-Vietoris theorem for this homology? I.e. a way to recover the homology of $M$ from the homologies of the three smaller sets.

Have you looked at any stratified Morse theory material? Handling boundaries etc. falls classically in that direction.

@user176372 I'm not familiar with it.

The standard reference is Goresky and MacPherson's book. http://www.math.ias.edu/~goresky/pdf/SMT.djvu. Regrettably, I haven't found the time and excuse to read through much of this carefully. CTRL+F doesn't bring up a direct reference to MV, but one of their main theorems is bound to imply what you want if it's standard. In the standard Morse theory case of manifolds without boundary, the Morse homology is isomorphic with singular homology and you ought to inherit MV from that isomorphism. I suppose you could also try to check the Eilenberg-Steenrod axioms for your case, which gives MV.
